# How to specify template function for STL container?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I need to write values of different types to a `std::wstringstream`. At one time we need to write one ore more values. I have tried to implement it like this:

```
wstringstream _str;     

template<typename ValueType> //(1)
void WriteValue(const ValueType& val)
{
    _str << val;
}

template<typename ValueType> //(2)
void WriteValue(const std::vector<ValueType>& vals)
{
    for (auto it = vals.begin(); it!= vals.end(); ++it)
    {
        WriteValue<ValueType>(*it);
        _str << L" ";            
    }
}

template<typename ValueType>
void WriteRecord(const std::wstring& name, const ValueType & val)
{
     _str << name;
     WriteValue<ValueType>(val);
}

void Foo()
{
    int bar = 0;
    WriteRecord<int>(L"Lorem", bar); //it's okay

    std::vector<int> buz(4, 0);
    WriteRecord<int>(L"ipsum", buz); //it's error
}
```

I got the following error :

```
"cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::vector< int, std::allocator < int > >' 
to 'int &'". As seen compiler tries to pass a vector to (1), not (2).
```

Why so? Is it possible to make it choose (2) specialized function template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WriteRecord<int>(L"ipsum", buz);
           ^^^^^
```

Here you explicitly say that `ValueType` should be an `int`. So the function signature is:

```
void WriteRecord(const std::wstring& name, const int& val)
```

And when you try to pass a `std::vector` as second argument, the compiler can't convert the `std::vector` to an `int`.

For functions, there is rarely a need to explicitly name the type of the template argument, you writing the call like this will work:

```
WriteRecord(L"ipsum", buz); //Compiler deduces ValueType
```

---

If you really need to specify the template argument, use `decltype`:

```
WriteRecord<decltype(buz)>(L"ipsum", buz);
```

or just write it out (not recommended)

```
WriteRecord<std::vector<int>>(L"ipsum", buz);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> buz(4, 0);
WriteRecord<int>(L"ipsum", buz);
//          ^^^
```

You're telling the compiler `ValueType` is `int` but then you're passing `vector<int>` as the argument. The compiler is perfectly capable of deducing template argument types, so stop specifying them everywhere unnecessarily. Your `Foo` function should look like this:

```
void Foo()
{
    int bar = 0;
    WriteRecord(L"Lorem", bar);

    std::vector<int> buz(4, 0);
    WriteRecord(L"ipsum", buz);
}
```

Similarly, remove the explicitly specified template arguments in the calls to `WriteValue` in the other functions.